# Flask app not updating the page on reloading after being deployed on heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

So I have made a pretty basic flask app which shows a plotly graph template. The code pulls data from a database and updates the template, which should be reflected on the app when I reload. It works like a charm locally but when I push it on heroku, it doesn't seem to work at all. I'm not able to understand the issue here. I'll attach the code below.

```py
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

def dir_last_updated(folder):
    return str(max(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root_path, f))
                   for root_path, dirs, files in os.walk(folder)
                   for f in files))

@app.route("/")
def totalNodeCount():
    plot = gp.Plot()
    plot.plotData() #Fetches data from a database and updated the testTemplate.html
    return render_template("testTemplate.html", last_updated = dir_last_updated("templates"))

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
    app.run(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 8080)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated :) Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. _Specifically_, what do you mean by "it doesn't seem to work at all"? Your title and most of the question body suggest that your application works in general but fails to do one specific thing, however looking at your `app.run()` with a hard-coded port of 8080 I suspect your app isn't even starting.

Comment: @Chris So, what I mean here is that, the app, when I run it locally and make changes to the database, those specific changes are reflected to the template. However, when I push it to heroku and make the changes then the situation becomes very arbitrary, the changes I make to the database are either reflected after a long time(hours sometimes) or it's not able to pick up the changes. So, the database my app uses is hosted as a different app on heroku itself, which might be an issue, but the main problem is that heroku is not able to pick up the changes made to the database instantaneously.

Comment: I've tried using the different ways people suggested for other questions similar to this, but none seem to work.

Comment: Well, again, I'm pretty sure this code _won't work_ on Heroku due to the wrong port being used. Please make sure to show us _actual_ representative code, ideally as a [mre]. We can't be expected to guess at what you are really doing.

Comment: What are `gp`, `gp.Plot()`, and `plot.plotData()` here? It sounds like the issue is somewhere in here, possibly in `plotData()`. We can't help with code we can't see. Again, please read [ask].